# Python - cannot import OpenCV module?

Tags: raspbian, python, opencv

I used [this](http://www.pyimagesearch.com/2015/02/23/install-opencv-and-python-on-your-raspberry-pi-2-and-b/) guide which installs OpenCV in a virtual environment, however I am getting the following error when I try to import the `cv2` module:

```
$ source ~/.profile
$ workon cv
$ python
>>> import cv2
Traceback (most recent call last):
   File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: No module named cv2
```

As far as I can see OpenCV is installed:

```
$ pkg-config --modversion opencv
$ 2.4.10
```

Answer (score 5):

Installing openCV does not include the python bindings.  You need to install these packages as well:

```
sudo apt-get install libopencv-dev python-opencv
```